# Access ORM models from different classes in Odoo/OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I am aware that you can get a reference to an existing model from within another model by using `self.pool.get('my_model')`

My question is, how can I get a reference to a model from a Python class that does NOT extend 'Model'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you will have to import the class like a normal Python class, writing in your .py file:

```
from your_path_class import YourClass
```

And then you will be able to work with it:

```
Yourclass.any_method()
```

By the way, `self.pool.get('your model')` in Odoo 8 API is `self.env['your_model']`.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty basic and simple any python class can be called from it's name space,  so call your class from namespace and instanciate the class.

Even Model class or any class inherited from Model can be called and instanciated like this.

Self.pool is just orm cache to access framework persistent layer.

Bests